# knockout-validation - Custom Template Validation Messages are not changing

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-validation, validationmessage

I have set up an example in JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/4stu2jg3/63/

In the first textbox if you add a non-numeric number and click the button is will show the required message. I would assume this should be showing the number message since there is a value?

In the second textbox if you delete the string and click the button is will show the number message. I would expect this to show the required message?

If you comment out the custom template everything works as I would expect it to. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
<div id="test">
    <div><input data-bind="value: first" /></div>
    <div><input data-bind="value: last" /></div>

    <input type="button" value="Validate" />
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="qmsKoValidationTemplate">
    <span class="qms-val-panel" data-bind="visible: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(), text: field.error"></span>
</script>

ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messageTemplate: "qmsKoValidationTemplate"
});

var t = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.first = ko.observable()
        .extend({required: { message: 'Required' } })
        .extend({number: { message: 'Number' } });

    self.last = ko.observable('Del')
        .extend({required: { message: 'Required' } })
        .extend({number: { message: 'Number' } });
}

var s = new t();

ko.applyBindings(s, document.getElementById('test'));

$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {    
    //console.log(s.first(), s.last());
    //console.log(ko.validatedObservable(s).isValid())
    ko.validatedObservable(s).isValid()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of debug, `ko.isObservable(field.error)` returns false which would explain the "not changing" aspect of the issue.

In looking closer, the [custom binding](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/bindingHandlers.js) `validationMessage` is used in the default template. Replacing the `text` binding with this custom binding appears to provide the desired behavior.

```
<span class="qms-val-panel" data-bind="visible: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(), validationMessage: field">        
</span>
```

[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4stu2jg3/66/)